# Laravel Repository file changes not working

Tags: php, laravel, caching, repository-pattern, laravel-artisan

I have changed one of my repository files. But the changes doesn't working and still getting errors with referring to old file. I tried clearing the cache, but still not working. Below cache clearings tried.

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan optimize:clear
```

**Clearing the linux cache**

```
htcacheclean
rm -rf /var/www/cache/*
```

**Composer autoload also tried**

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Is anyone got this issue previously and found solution.

Comment: You mean PHP is not getting updated on your server.
or is it an assets file like JS, image, CSS etc?

Comment: PHP code in Model Repository file is not updating.